# Installing windows service using command prompt

Tags: windows, installation

I was hoping that this would be an easy installation. I was trying to install a windows service on a server (Windows Server 2008 R2) by using the following command prompt.

InstallUtil.exe WeeklyCloseProcessService.exe /servicename=”WeeklyCloseProcessService_2” /servicedisplayname= ”WeeklyCloseProcessService_2”

When I run this command, it successfully installs the windows service. but it seems to create the windows service with a display name including the quotes ”WeeklyCloseProcessService_2”.

I am not sure what is happening and any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Try this -->

```
InstallUtil.exe WeeklyCloseProcessService.exe /servicename=”WeeklyCloseProcessService_2, /servicedisplayname=WeeklyCloseProcessService_2”
```

or

```
InstallUtil.exe WeeklyCloseProcessService.exe /servicename=”WeeklyCloseProcessService_2", /servicedisplayname="WeeklyCloseProcessService_2”
```

Comment: Hi Du6e, Thanks for the quick response. I manually typed the command along with the quotes and did not have a spaces between the = sing and the next letter and it worked !!  Thanks for your quick response !!